# How to troubleshoot why my provider hosted app won't upload

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app

I have followed some directions exactly on a youtube video for deploying a provider hosted add in from visual studio 2017. The youtube video also matches the Microsoft docs. I signed up for a new O365 tenant and have provisioned a single developer site collection in the SharePoint Admin Center.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HWc3Z8q13jA

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/register-sharepoint-add-ins

Yet, at the final step where I upload my .app file to the developer site, SharePoint provides a vague error message. How can I get a more detailed error message to try and figure out what has gone wrong?

[image]

Comment: The error states that there is something wrong with your package-file you are trying to upload. Are you sure you have uploaded the correct file?

Comment: Yeah, it's literally the only .app file I've ever made :-)